# AssertionError in Cypress: alias is displayed as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, cypress, alias

I'm trying to understand aliases in Cypress and have an issue.
I want to save total price in cart value to use it in further check:

```
cy.get("#totalp").invoke('text').then(parseInt).as('totalPriceInCart');
```

After that, I want to make sure that the text in purchase confirmation has the same value:

```
cy.get('.lead').should('be.visible').then((domElementWithText) => {
            expect(text).to.include('Amount: ' + cy.get('@totalPriceInCart') + ' USD');
          });
```

Eventually, I have the following AssertionError:
expected 'Amount: 360 USD' to include 'Amount: [object Object] USD'
How should I change my code in order to have my test passed?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use another `.then()` to get the alias value, according to the docs:

```js
cy.get('@totalPriceInCart').then(totalPriceInCart => {
  cy.get('.lead').should('be.visible').should((domElementWithText) => {
     expect(text).to.include('Amount: ' + totalPriceInCart + ' USD');
  })
})
```

The thing you describe as `[object Object]` is the Chainer object, but you will not be able to match it to the text in that way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Because the check comes in my code some time after saving the alias, I wrote it like this, and it worked. I hope there are no mistakes here:
`cy.get('.lead').should('be.visible');`  

`cy.get('@totalPriceInCart').then((totalPriceInCart) => {`  
    `cy.get('.lead').invoke('text').as('alertText');  const expectedPriceText = 'Amount: ' + totalPriceInCart + ' USD';  `  
    `cy.get('@alertText').should('include', expectedPriceText);`
    `// some other checks 
});`